# Git config to push <foo_local_branch>:<bar_remote_branch> by default?

Tags: git, heroku, config, staging

I'm looking to set up a clean deploy approach for both production and staging on heroku and was wondering about a fairly subtle git behavior. We have two heroku apps up and running, and my .git/config looks like:

```
[remote "prod"]
     url = https://git.heroku.com/<appname>.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[remote "staging"]
     url = https://git.heroku.com/<appname>.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

So if I want to push my main repo’s `master` branch to `staging`, the command would be:

```
$ git push staging master
```

But in our workflow, we use a `staging` branch to consolidate features that are in development. Deploying the `staging` branch to the staging app then requires:

```
$ git push staging staging:master
```

Question: is there any configuration setting for git that would allow me to push the local `staging` branch to the remote `master` branch by default? Ie, I would like to run:

```
 $ git push staging master
```

or even better

```
$ git push staging
```

and what would be executed would have the same effect as git push staging staging:master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the upstream branch of your local *staging* branch to stating/master

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=staging/master
```

If you now run git push from your local staging branch, you will push to staging/master

You can also tell git to track a particular remote branch when creating your local branch

```
git checkout -b staging staging/master
```

And you can see which remote branch your local branch is tracking

```
git branch -vv
```

Comment: @qfinder In addition tl creating the local branch with `git checkout -b staging staging/master` or `git branch staging/master staging`, re-creating it with `git checkout -B staging staging/master` or `git branch -f staging/master staging` will also have set the local branch's upstream in this way. Unless you've changed `git config branch.autosetupmerge`.